# Specify Parquet properties pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

How to specify Parquet Block Size and Page Size in PySpark? I have searched everywhere but cannot find any documentation for the function calls or the import libraries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [spark-user archives](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-user/201410.mbox/%3C9DEF4C39-DFC2-411B-8987-5B9C33842974@videoamp.com%3E)

```
sc.hadoopConfiguration.setInt("dfs.blocksize", some_value)
sc.hadoopConfiguration.setInt("parquet.block.size", some_value)
```

so in PySpark

```
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().setInt("dfs.blocksize", some_value)
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().setInt("parquet.block.size", some_value)
```