# PySpark Write Parquet Binary Column with Stats (signed-min-max.enabled)

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark, parquet, parquet-mr

I found this apache-parquet ticket https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PARQUET-686 which is marked as resolved for `parquet-mr` 1.8.2. The feature I want is the calculated `min/max` in the parquet metadata for a (`string` or `BINARY`) column.

And referencing this is an email https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/%3CCANPCBc2UPm+oZFfP9oT8gPKh_v0_BF0jVEuf=Q3d-5=ugxSFbQ@mail.gmail.com%3E
 which uses `scala` instead of `pyspark` as an example:

> ```
>      Configuration conf = new Configuration();
>         + conf.set("parquet.strings.signed-min-max.enabled", "true");
>      Path inputPath = new Path(input);
>      FileStatus inputFileStatus =
>        inputPath.getFileSystem(conf).getFileStatus(inputPath);
>      List<Footer> footers = ParquetFileReader.readFooters(conf, inputFileStatus, false);
> ```

I've been unable to set this value in `pyspark` (perhaps I'm setting it in the wrong place?)

---

**example dataframe**

```
import random
import string
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType    

r = []
for x in range(2000):
    r.append(u''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(10)))

df = spark.createDataFrame(r, StringType())
```

I've tried a few different ways of setting this option:

```
df.write.format("parquet").option("parquet.strings.signed-min-max.enabled", "true").save("s3a://test.bucket/option")
df.write.option("parquet.strings.signed-min-max.enabled", "true").parquet("s3a://test.bucket/option")
df.write.option("parquet.strings.signed-min-max.enabled", True).parquet("s3a://test.bucket/option")
```

But all of the saved parquet files are missing the ST/STATS for the BINARY column. Here is an example output of the metadata from one of the parquet files:

```
creator:     parquet-mr version 1.8.3 (build aef7230e114214b7cc962a8f3fc5aeed6ce80828)
extra:       org.apache.spark.sql.parquet.row.metadata = {"type":"struct","fields":[{"name":"value","type":"string","nullable":true,"metadata":{}}]}

file schema: spark_schema
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
value:       OPTIONAL BINARY O:UTF8 R:0 D:1

row group 1: RC:33 TS:515
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

Also, based on this email chain https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-user/201410.mbox/%3C9DEF4C39-DFC2-411B-8987-5B9C33842974@videoamp.com%3E and question: [Specify Parquet properties pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38236892/specify-parquet-properties-pyspark)

I tried sneaking the config in through the pyspark private API:

```
spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().setBoolean("parquet.strings.signed-min-max.enabled", True)
```

So I am still unable to set this conf `parquet.strings.signed-min-max.enabled` in `parquet-mr` (or it is set, but something else has gone wrong)

1. Is it possible to configure `parquet-mr` from pyspark
2. Does pyspark 2.3.x support BINARY column stats?
3. How do I take advantage of the PARQUET-686 feature to add `min/max` metadata for string columns in a parquet file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since historically Parquet writers wrote wrong min/max values for UTF-8 strings, new Parquet implementations skip those stats during reading, unless `parquet.strings.signed-min-max.enabled` is set. So this setting is a **read** option that tells the Parquet library to trust the min/max values in spite of their known deficiency. The only case when this setting can be safely enabled is if the strings only contain ASCII characters, because the corresponding bytes for those will never be negative.

Since you use `parquet-tools` for dumping the statistics and  `parquet-tools` itself uses the Parquet library, it will ignore string min/max statistics by default. Although it seems that there are no min/max values in the file, in reality they are there, but get ignored.

The proper solution for this problem is [PARQUET-1025](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PARQUET-1025), which introduces new statistics fields `min-value` and `max-value`. These handle UTF-8 strings correctly.