# Parquet files not having stats from String column when using Hive

Tags: apache-spark, hive, parquet

I used Spark to write some data directly to Parquet, one without Hive and one with Hive. 
This is how I write directly without Hive

```
cube_op.sort("asn").write.parquet("/home/hadoop/work/aaa/agg1")
```

I see that min max stats are present for all columns. 
However when I run the same and write to Hive, I do not see min max for the string columns. Here is how I write using Hive

```
cube_op.sort("asn").write.insertInto("tbl1")
```

These are the properties I have given

```
spark.sql("SET spark.sql.parquet.binaryAsString=true")
"parquet.strings.signed-min-max.enabled": "true"
```

I am not sure what could be the reason for the difference. This is the hive version.

```
hive --version
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/ais/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.16.2-1.cdh5.16.2.p0.8/jars/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
...
Hive 1.1.0-cdh5.16.2
```

This is apparently the parquet version with Hive

```
creator: parquet-mr version 1.6.0 (build 6aa21f877662518059cfebe7f2e00cb)
```

Comment: what is spark version and parquet dependency version is it spark-1.6.0+cdh5.16.2 ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PySpark Write Parquet Binary Column with Stats (signed-min-max.enabled)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53158121/pyspark-write-parquet-binary-column-with-stats-signed-min-max-enabled)

Comment: This could be due to the parquet version. I see a difference between the two parquet versions i.e when I write directly vs when I write via Hive

Comment: I did try the approach in the stack overflow, but did not work. Thanks